# Two-level Tree Navigation in Beamer

Tags: beamer, themes, navigation

I'm curious what would be an effective work-around for the Beamer tree outer theme package that would allow for two-level navigation instead of the default three-level navigation.

For example, I'm rather partial to this format: http://www.math.umbc.edu/~rouben/beamer/beamer_pstricks.pdf

In this presentation, the subsubsection is a horizontal tree to the subsection.  How would I go about doing this?  Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine the `headline` template as defined in `beamerouterthemetree.sty`, to give you the desired layout; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{tree}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
      \ifbeamer@tree@showhooks
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsectionhead}%
        \ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt%
          \hskip2pt\raise1.9pt\hbox{\vrule width0.4pt height1.875ex\vrule width 5pt height0.4pt}%
          \hskip1pt%
        \fi%
      \else%  
        \hskip6pt%
      \fi%
      \insertsectionhead
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}%
      \ifbeamer@tree@showhooks
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsubsectionhead}%
        \ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt%
          \ \raise1.9pt\hbox{\vrule width 5pt height0.4pt}%
          \hskip1pt%
        \fi%
      \else%  
        \hskip12pt%
      \fi%
      \insertsubsectionhead\hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace{0.5em}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother
\title{Tree Outer Theme}
\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Some images of the resulting headlines, showing the desired layout:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: @user27383 You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: If it wouldn't be considered bothersome of me to ask, how could I best adjust that second `beamercolorbox`to include a frame number/total frame number like seen in that PDF listed above (which would probably be its own `beamercolorbox` and adjusted to the right)?

Please forgive my lack of awareness, I'm trying to make some Beamer themes for my department and having to teach myself from scratch.

Comment: @user27383 It's not bothersome at all; there's no need for a new `beamercolorbox`; looking at the position of the numbers, they use the same box as the section/subsection heads; it's enough to use a `\hfill` and insert the numbers and then leave some little `\hspace`, as I did in my updated answer. Now it's my time to bother you: please, if you consider that my answer solved your problem, don't forget to up-vote it and accept it (they are two different actions); in case of doubt about accepting answers, please see [`How do you accept an answer?`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: +1, very helpful.  I signed up for TeX StackExchange in order to vote this answer up.